# What does it mean when strcmp has a plus sign?

Tags: c, addition, strcmp

Some C code I am working on has the following line,

```
strcmp(str1+4, str2);
```

strcmp returns,

- 0 for equal ASCII values of both strings
- '1' for where str1 has a greater ASCII value than str2
- '-1' where str1 has a lesser ASCII value than str2

Given this notation, is it possible 'str1+4' is the ASCII value of 'str1' and then adding 4 or is it indicative of something else?

I looked around online and through documentation without much in the way of luck and figured I'd ask here to clarify my understanding.

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with `strcmp`, which simply takes a pointer to a string.  The thing you should be asking is what does `str1+4` mean, when `str1` is a `char *`.  Search for "pointer arithmetic".

Comment: That line compares str1 (from the 5th character) and the whole str2. `char * foo = "stackOverflow";` foo+3 = "ckOverflow", it's the same as &foo[3] by definition

Comment: Your statement about return value of `strcmp` is wrong. It can return any number, not only `-1`, `0`, `1`. You need to read the spec carefully.

Comment: concreteCozy, "'1' for where str1 has a greater ASCII value than str2" is amiss too.  ASCII only well defined for 0-127.  `strcmp()` return a positive value when the compared strings differ, as `unsigned char` values (0-255) and first first is greater than the 2nd.